# why does this php code not work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a BOOLEAN in my table, set to 0 or 1.

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM mydb WHERE email = 'admin@mail.com'") or die(mysql_error());

if ($test == 0) { 
    echo "FF";
} elseif ($test == 1) { 
    echo "ON";
}
```

But this doesn't work, why? I tried true and false, that doesn´t work either.

Comment: In what sense does it "not work"? Error message? Unexpected echo value? What's the value in `$test` after that `mysql_query` call?

Comment: Is the name of your _table_ really `mydb`?

Comment: how you can test the variable value without getting the value of record, you need to fetch the result from your query by **mysql_fetch_array** or **mysql_fetch_object** what ever you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually fetching the result.

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM mydb WHERE email = 'admin@mail.com'");
if (!$test) {
    die(mysql_error());
} else {
    $res = $test;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

var_dump($row);
```

Comment: Maybe OP just wanted to `$test` if the query was run?

Answer (score 0):

$test is just the results from the query. You want to see if you get a row try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM mydb WHERE email = 'admin@mail.com'")or die(mysql_error());

$row_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($row_count == 0)
{
  echo "FF";
}
else if($row_count == 1)
{
  echo "ON";
}
```

If you need to know the value of `status`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM mydb WHERE email = 'admin@mail.com'")or die(mysql_error());

 while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    if($data['status'] == 0)
    {
      echo "FF";
    }
    else if($data['status'] == 1)
    {
      echo "ON";
    }
 }
```